# Link de um parâmetro JSON para um produto no Woocommerce

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um JSON que me retorna uma lista com alguns dados de vôo:

```
  "programa": "multiplus",
  "qtdOpcoesIda": 50,
  "qtdOpcoesVolta": 50,
  "menorTarifa": {
    "pontos": 15000,
    "dinheiro": 767.8
  },
  "taxaEmbarque": {
    "POA": 29.9,
    "FLN": 29.9
  },
  "passagens": [
    {
      "pontos": 23000,
      "dinheiro": 738.9,
      "opcoesIda": [
        {
```

Estou imprimindo esses dados numa tabela com botões "SELECIONAR VÔO" (ainda sem referência, porque empaquei nisso) para cada vôo separadamente. Como eu faria para que esses botões usassem os parâmetros "programa" e "pontos" individuais de cada vôo para buscar produtos no woocommerce que tivessem como categoria o determino programa, e o mínimo de pontos do resultado?

Ficarei feliz se puderem ajudar...

Comment: Ack Lay, obrigado por ajustar o conteúdo da maneira adequada, foi minha primeira interação aqui, e eu não li as normas de postagem, estava com pressa. Parece que a saudação é desnecessária, né.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você precisa acessar as propriedades desse JSON, certo? Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) pra tranformar em um objeto:

```
$json = '{ "programa": "multiplus", ... }';
$objeto = json_decode( $json );

echo $objeto->programa; // 'multiplus'
echo $objeto->menorTarifa->pontos; // '15000'
echo $objeto->passagens[0]->pontos; // '23000'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Ricardo, isso já me da um caminho para minha resolução. Valeu